# JSON из инета в JS массив

Tags: javascript, json

у меня есть так скажем страничка гугла с json данными
на нее есть только ссылка но это веб приложение которое выплевывает json
я пока знаю только фронт и бэк не изучал я не знаю как с этим работать пожалуйста помогите
просто требуется преобразовать json в массив яваскрипта ну или просто скажите как с ними работать

{"result":[["А.С.Пушкин","Руслан и людмила",5]

вот отрывок для примера
мне надо будет сравнить значения из текст инпутов с первыми двумя и вывести 3ье
если вдруг понадобится то вот ссылка на приложение гугл:

https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=hINCyiz3icrDw0xNr1TmmHkETYa3XvGwe_8P3W8HZRouqfGuJ4jc7jGTR6WkwUnQCAGq7HKP1NlfqAU7Nob8mnLBYXO00GuIm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnIzN51vUxWtuGsKQ97o_jtgyl-HoOaplriXZIlJfruDEW0aitzwQyyEAFDVzyWwL_dfhFHZILP7b9qsVYlDlfkUzogxxO2xArtz9Jw9Md8uu&lib=MgUHGDume1lla1kmps2VAVSU8rTdR3aKb

Comment: прошу прощения энтеры ставил но видимо надо было <br>

Comment: Абсолютно не понятно что нужно и причём тут бэк

Comment: А по ссылке думаете кто пойдёт? А вдруг там вирус. Нет, спасибо

Comment: ну как минимум это гугл ссылка -_- при возможности я бы прикрепил скрин

Comment: а у меня задача одна преобразовать json получаемый get`ом в массив ну илил просто хоть как то поработать с ним

Comment: надо помещать код в вопрос (а его можно редактировать)....... что значит преобразовать json в массив? а что сейчас не так? вон же массив........... а какой результат нужен? и причём тут бэк, опять же?

Answer (score 0):

По вашему вопросу мало что понятно.. В место ссылки, по которой переходить никто не будет, лучше бы прикрепили скриншот.
Возможно, вам поможет
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse